# Refresh standard page inside a button that adds contents (a file) to it?

Tags: apex, visualforce

So I have a standard page, A, inside which I've embedded a button through the salesforce button interface. This button basically generates a PDF and associates it to the record on page A.

I have succesfully made it so that it can attach the file to the page, and can navigate back to the record for page A after the button is clicked, however the file does not show up as linked to the record (YET). Instead, I have to refresh the page to get it to appear. How can I refresh the standard page after the button press?

The button press leads us to this 'page' which does no actual rendering.

```
<apex:page controller="Welcome_lettr_Controller" action="{!createLetter}" >
</apex:page>
```

Below is the code for createLetter

```
Public PageReference createLetter(){
    dummyFn();
    // Returning to the patients main page
    String url_prefix = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    url_prefix = url_prefix + '/one/one.app#/sObject/';

    String url_end = '';
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url_prefix + id  + url_end);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}

Public PageReference dummyFn(){
    // some code here which ties the generated file to the record
    // this actually generates another visualforce page and populates that with
    // relevant data
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a lot like this known issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU
"When data is updated from an Apex controller and redirected to the detail page in Lightning Experience, the updated data is not seen in the UI, even though the data is updated in the database..."

Comment: Sorry, I really did look around but I didn't think to look in the bugs section. I thought it was just a lack of knowledge on my end. I'll close up the issue now